# Does Brackets (editor) have bundles like textmate

Tags: editor, twig, bundle, adobe-brackets

I just downloaded brackets after hearing recent buzz about the editor. There are some really cool / useful features out of the box.

Alot of my projects use templating engines, like twig. Does this editor support bundles for other filetypes? I have been using textmate for a while and by simply downloading the twig bundle I have highlighting and code snippets integrated into the editor. I am hoping brackets has a similar feature.

Comment: Surely this would be .. documented on the appropriate website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: not yet, but soon.

Longer answer:

- APIs for Brackets extensions to add a new syntax/language [are currently in progress](https://trello.com/card/0-research-language-extensibility/4f90a6d98f77505d7940ce88/712), and will probably be done in about a month.
- Since Brackets uses the [CodeMirror editor](http://codemirror.net), syntax highlighting is driven by CodeMirror "modes." It doesn't appear that anyone has made a Twig mode yet. But it might not be too hard to build one, either based on the [sample code for Mustache highlighting](http://codemirror.net/demo/mustache.html) or the new ["multiplexing mode" feature](http://codemirror.net/demo/multiplex.html) in CodeMirror 3  (Brackets is updating to CodeMirror 3 soon).
- Brackets may eventually support [directly importing TextMate language bundles](https://trello.com/card/support-textmate-language-grammar-bundles/4f90a6d98f77505d7940ce88/602), like Sublime does, but that's a ways off.

As a stopgap, you could have Brackets just highlight Twig files as plain HTML -- better than no color coding at all. That'll be doable with the upcoming extension APIs, but if you're feeling adventurous you could hack your current copy of Brackets to do that right now. Just dig into the app folder, open *www/editor/EditorUtils.js*, and add the file extension after the `case "html":` line.

(p.s. - I work on the Brackets core team. Thanks for giving Brackets a try!)

Comment: Sweet thx! If i find some time i might try to hack into the EditorUtils file!

Comment: Update: as of our latest build, [Brackets now highlights .twig files as plain HTML](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/3362), as suggested above. Richer syntax coloring (e.g. highlighting binding expressions) is still waiting on a CodeMirror mode.

Comment: Any updates on this? Please update accordingly, this answer is listed as #1 for me when I google ```adobe brackets twig```